# Socket.IO not working from Angular despite allowing origin

Tags: node.js, angular, socket.io, cors

I am trying to use socket.io to connect my angular 8 app to my node.js server, my app is using REST endpoints on the same server without issue but socket.io always fails with CORS related error.

This is the relevant part from my server:

```
const app: Application = express();

app.use(cors({credentials: false}));

// The application will have it's routes on /api
app.use("/api", routes);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+'/public/')));
// Everything else will be redirected to the FE app
app.all("/*", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/public/index.html'));
})

let port = process.env.PORT || configs.port;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server online on port', port);
});

let server = require('http').Server(app);
let io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: ['http://localhost:4200'] });
// io.origins(['http://localhost:4200']);

io.on('connection', function (socket: Socket) {
    console.log('WEB SOCKET CONNECTION');
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data: any) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

And this is on the client:

```
    this.socket = io.connect(configs.baseURL);
```

The error in full is:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N1QG96g' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.**

Thank you for reading, I've googled this error message and found some fixes like my attempt to add the client to the origins on the server but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

pass `origin: true` to the cors middleware

```
app.use(cors({credentials: false, origin: true}));
```